# Rails Posgres db: WARNING: unrecognized node type: 112

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, friendly-id

I am getting the following error in the production version of my Rails Postgres db:

> WARNING:  unrecognized node type: 112

It only happens in production, on basic console commands, such as .find, and on different models. It does not affect display data on the front-end, just database commands. Specifically, I am trying to update slugs using FriendlyID and am unable to in production (dev was fine) due to this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Additional information that is likely to be useful. Rails Version? PostgreSQL version? Any extensions you might be using? Any differences between your development environment and your production environment?

Comment: @engineermnky I just had to upgrade versions. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This is warning - probably from PostgreSQL or from some extension. Theoretically you can ignore this. Unfortunately without more details isn't possible to say, what is reason of this warning. It can depends on PostgreSQL version, it can depends on used extensions. Maybe this warning is red herring.